# Need Assistance in deploying Redmine in azure as PaaS

Tags: azure

I am trying to run redmine in Microsoft Azure in Web App.I have created a web app (in Ruby Runtime Environment) and have installed the redmine stack in it (through SSH). But i am not able to run redmine through that web app. I know there is a one click solution for redmine. But it will create a virtual machine which is IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service).But i want to deploy redmine as PaaS (Platform as a Service) in azure. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide information on what you already tried as well as minimal reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: One of the simplest ways would be to use a redmine Docker Image on Azure WebApp for Containers: https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine